# Pound sign in #define function parameters

Tags: c++

What does the pound sign indicate in this line of code?

```
#define CONDITION(x)    if(!(x)){ HandleError(#x,__FUNCTION__,__LINE__);return false;}
```

This is how it is being called:

```
CONDITION(foo != false);
```

Comment: AFAIK It's stringifying the condition. so you'll get "foo != false" in the handleerror call.

Comment: It will replace whatever passed to x at #x.

Comment: £ is pound sign
# is a hash symbol

Comment: @Anonymouse: Except in American English, where # is a pound sign (sometimes used to represent a pound weight), hash is banned in most states, and £ is a symbol of colonial oppression. If you want to be unambiguous, it's an "octothorpe". Or just #, since we're typing not speaking.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Same in Canada. It's probably a NA vs Europe distinction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A single `#` before a macro parameter converts it to a string literal.

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
STRINGIFY(hello)   // expands to "hello"
```

In your example, the string would be `"foo != false"`, so that the error message shows the code that was being tested.

A double `##` between two tokens within a macro combines them into a single token

```
#define GLOM(x,y) x ## y
GLOM(hello, World) // expands to helloWorld
```

Comment: can you elaborate on the double pound example.

Comment: @ahujamoh: As I said, it combines two tokens to make a single token (in the example, `hello` and `World` are combined to make `helloWorld`). I'm not sure how I can elaborate further, but your introductory book should describe it in detail.